# Database error when adding an object to a ManyToMany field

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

so I've been trying to create a list of staff, that is additional people who are allowed to for now, see and modify the project that is created in a generic Django app. The problem is, when creating a project and adding the user that created it to the staff_list field, I get an error

```
OperationalError at /projects/create/
no such column: projectManager_project_staff_list.project_id
```

My Project model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from folderManager.models import Folder
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from trackManager.models import Track
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Project (models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1) #the author
    staff_list = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = "Staff")
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("projects:project_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]

    @property
    def tracks(self):
        instance = self
        qs = Track.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
        return qs

    @property
    def get_content_type(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type
```

My Project Create view:

```
def project_create(request):
form = ProjectForm(request.POST or None)
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username) 
'''
    tried to see if using a defined user variable instead of request.user would help
'''
if form.is_valid():
    title_text =  form.cleaned_data.get('title')
    description_data = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
    instance = form.save(commit=False)

    instance.save()

    new_project = Project.objects.get_or_create(             
            title = title_text,
            description = description_data
        )
    newest_project = new_project[0]
    newest_project.staff_list.add(user)
    newest_project.save()
    #messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
context = {
    "form": form,
    }
return render(request, "project_form/project_form.html", context)
```

Latest migration:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11 on 2017-05-09 11:58
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Project',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField(unique=True)),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('timestamp', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('staff_list', models.ManyToManyField(related_name='Staff', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(default=1, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['-timestamp', '-updated'],
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Have you changed these models since originally creating them? If so have you run migrations?

Comment: Yes, I've ran migrations. I tried deleting the old database and migrating it from scratch, so that every table would be generated anew.

Comment: Can you show the migration that created the staff_list through table, then?

Comment: Dropped the code in the original question.